# Python - csv to dictionary - How to preserve encoding

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a very short script that should read a csv file and transform it into a dictionary:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'), delimiter=',')

words = {}

for row in reader:
    id = row[0]
    w3w = row[1]

    words[id] = w3w

print words
```

The csv file:

```
id,w3w
0,staring.riversidex.scarred
1,monosyllabe.prédicable.arrondi
2,kingpin.COVERS.blackmail
3,дружный.ярус.борта
4,rien.du.tout
5,nightfall.into.bucket
6,запас.союз.дружный
```

And the output:

```
{'1': 'monosyllabe.pr\xc3\xa9dicable.arrondi', '0': 'staring.riversidex.scarred', '3': '\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9.\xd1\x8f\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81.\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0', '2': 'kingpin  COVERS', '5': 'nightfall.into.bucket', '4': 'rien.du.tout', '6': '\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81.\xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd1\x8e\xd0\xb7.\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9', 'id': 'w3w'}
```

How can I keep the correct encoding in the dictionary?

Using Python 2.7

==EDIT==

Despite the apparences, my code actually works properly. See comment from  Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi

Comment: It's already correct. `print words['3']`. You will get this: `дружный.ярус.борта`. The unicode data is encoded in 'utf-8' format. You can encode it in some other format if you like. Python will represent the unicode data with ascii characters no matter which format you encode it into.

Comment: For a reason I don't understand, you are actually right! printing the whole dictionary doesn't properly display some characters but printing each value independently displays everything correctly. Thanks!